Application Error on Azure Portal When Accessing Domain
I am currently hosting my web application on Azure, and I am facing an issue when trying to access the application via its domain name. Upon clicking on the domain URL, I encounter an application error.
Here are the steps that lead to the issue:

I deployed my application (built using Django + Next.js) on Azure VM.
Configured the DNS and domain settings properly to point to the application.
However, when I click on the domain in the Azure portal or try accessing the application URL directly, I encounter an error page.

Error Details:

Error type: [Insert exact error, e.g., "500 Internal Server Error", "Application Error", or blank error message]
Environment: Azure Virtual Machine hosting Django + Next.js application
Last action before error: Clicking on domain name or accessing the deployed app URL directly.

What I've tried:
Verified that all the required dependencies are reinstalled.

Checked database connection settings after recent database changes.

Ensured that the correct application directory is in place, replacing previous Azure VM      configurations with the proper folder and updated connection settings.

Suggestions for debugging common application errors on Azure.

Steps to diagnose if this issue is related to the database connection setup.

Guidance on fixing deployment configuration conflicts or domain settings.


